# How does Angular bind an external javascript library to a declared var?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm looking to understand the mechanics of how Angular resolves a declared var to a specific javascript library. For example I reference a 3rd party javascript library and load it through index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="/assets/js/external.js"></script>
  ...
</html>
```

SomeComponent.ts

```
import ...

declare var functionA: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'some-component',
  templateUrl: 'some-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['some-component.css']
})
export class SomeComponent { ... }
```

does external.js have to have a function declared as `functionA`, to be resolved correctly? Or does Angular resolve it by matching the signature of `functionA` when I define the initial call to functionA in SomeComponent? And where can I find this documented - I'm probably not searching correctly.

Comment: this is not code i'm creating, it's code i've seen used over and over. I'm seeing it used in actual production code and was wondering how the resolution happens - whether it's idiomatically correct or not is not my ultimate question - how does Angular resolve it? Also note it's bringing in an external js library - potentially without typings ... the reason for any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`external.js` library can expose some of its objects or functions globally. It means that after the library is loaded you can access the exports from wherever you like on that page with `window.exportedFn()` or just `exportedFn()`. it is not usual way to pollute global with your functions, so typescript needs to be told that the exported thing exists and probably provide its signature. if the signature is wrong you won't get any compile time errors, because it is not linked anyhow. TS just believes that the signature is right. You will just get a runtime error if you are using your function in a wrong way

Comment: So some existing code I see in Angular declares a var where there is no matching function name, so I'm understanding by what you are stating that Angular will try to match it by signature ... other areas of the code the var declarations match the function names in the external.js file - so I was curious.
My guess is if there are other signatures that could match I would get some compiler error about ambiguous calls or some such. Am I on the right track?

Comment: again: for compiler you just force it to accept that the global function exists and it's signature is like this. it is not a c++ world where you need to link the "reference" and the object itself. it just will be found on runtime. So on compile time you will never know if the type you provided is right or wrong and you wil always l have to check if it works on runtime